# Monitoring/debugging SignalR data

Tags: javascript, signalr

How can I monitor the data that is being transmitted to and from my javascript client? I've tried using Google Chrome Developer Tools, but under Network tab when I select the web socket I can't see exact data that is being transmitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data should be under the "frames" tab in Chrome devtools.

[image]

If you can't get that to work, you can try fiddler2:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718660/Debug-Inspect-WebSocket-traffic-with-Fiddler